# How do I get the increase for a period of time?

Tags: promql

I have a counter in our application that increases any time a process starts. It has a bunch of labels, amongst others there is pod-name and customer-name. One could argue that it has a pretty high cardinality, and  the things we count can happen as low as 3 times per 24h interval and customer up to several hundreds occasions per 24h and customer.

I want to create a check if that number stops increasing, but my queries doesn't give me the right answer.

First I tried what I think the documentation says:

```
sum(increase(application_thing_added[24h]))
```

This give me a value of about a fourth of what I'm expecting. As there are no counter resets for now, I tried the following query

```
sum(application_thing_added) - sum(application_thing_added offset 24h)
```

which gives me the correct answer, but I know it won't work during a counter reset.

What is the best way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

The `sum(increase(application_thing_added[24h]))` returns unexpected result in Prometheus when applied to slow-changing counters because of extrapolation - see [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746).

Unfortunately Prometheus doesn't provide functionality, which could be used for reliable calculations of slow counter increase in the face of counter resets and counters starting from non-zero values :(

P.S. The same original query - `sum(increase(application_thing_added[24h]))` - returns the expected correct result in VictoriaMetrics - Prometheus-like monitoring system I work on. See [this article](https://medium.com/@romanhavronenko/victoriametrics-promql-compliance-d4318203f51e) and [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) for details.

Comment: I think I found out why it doesn't work as I expected.  As I mentioned, we have quite high cardinality and the problem seems to be that we create many time series but only after the first event has happened. 

So we create a time series with (pod, customerid)  with value 1 and from what I've read prometheus doesn't see that as an increase. I've been playing with VictoriaMetrics, and we're thinking of migrating to it - but how would VM handle this use case?

Comment: [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function in VictoriaMetrics returns proper (expected) results for time series starting from non-zero values. It also returns expected results for slow-changing integer counters. See [this article](https://medium.com/@romanhavronenko/victoriametrics-promql-compliance-d4318203f51e).